# How to stop execution of a user in Jmeter after certain data is downloaded

Tags: jmeter

I am testing the performance of a Internet speed test application being build by our company.
The scenario is each user will be downloading 6 files in parallel(six different http requests). So I am using blazemeter parallel controller to replicate this.
Each Jmeter thread will hit these 6 requests in parallel and will move to next iteration. 
Now we have to stop or kill the user after it has downloaded x MB of data.
Means any thread which has downloaded X Mb data in all the iterations will stop further iterations.

Comment: if you know per iteration how much MB is downloaded, stop after few iterations as per calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You could add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) which will be [retrieving the response size](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getBytesAsLong--) and check whether it exceeds defined threshold. If it is - you can call [setStopThread()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setStopThread-boolean-) function

Example code:

```
if (prev.getBytesAsLong() > 1000) {
    log.info("Sampler downloaded " + prev.getBytesAsLong() + " bytes, stopping")
    prev.setStopThread(true)
}
```

In the above snippet **prev** stands for the parent [HTTPSampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSampleResult.html), check out [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) article to learn more about [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for JSR223 Test Elements.